# Modify input field sizes in Flask-Admin

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-admin

Does anyone know of an easy way to specify a size for input fields in Flask-Admin?

E.g. setting `class="input-xlarge"` on an input field does the trick, but is there a simple way to do that from Flask-Admin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `form_widget_args`.

For example:

```
class MyModelView(BaseModelView):
    form_widget_args = {
        'description': {
            'rows': 10,
            'class': 'input-xlarge'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat dirty way, but still useful

```
class MyModelView(BaseModelView):    
    form_widget_args = {
        'description': {
            'rows': 20,
            'style':'width: 1000px;'
        }
    }
```