# Adjust field size in Flask-Admin w/ Bootstrap3

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask-admin

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249100/modify-input-field-sizes-in-flask-admin) but that solution seems to be for Bootstrap2 and has no affect on my code.

Would anyone know how to customize the field width in Flask-Admin?  I know it has something to do with `form_widget_args` but I haven't figured out the right combination yet.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I was able to solve some of this problem adding the following in the view:

```py
form_widget_args = {
    asset_tag:{'class': 'form-control',
               'style': "width: 40%",
               'placeholder':'ex. M132 or T456'
               }
```

This uses CSS to override the Bootstrap formatting.  I was hoping to be able to use Bootstrap Grid formatting (i.e. `.col-md-8`)